# Ubuntu purple terminal colors to iTerm2

Tags: macos, ubuntu, terminal, themes, iterm2

I've been looking for a iTerm2 theme that resembles the default purple Ubuntu terminal but have had no success so far.

Does a theme for the standard Ubuntu terminal exist for iTerm2 or will I have to create my own? If so, does anyone know the complete list of colors used by the Terminal?

**Note** By "complete list of colors" I mean the foreground color, background color, bold color and the palette.

Here is a screenshot of the terminal in action.

[image: Ubuntu default purple terminal]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the palette

```
Background 300A24
Foreground FFFFFF (not sure, text is anti-aliased)
Color0 2E3436
Color1 CC0000
Color2 4E9A06
Color3 C4A000
Color4 3465A4
Color5 75507B
Color6 06989A
Color7 D3D7CF
```

[image: Standard colors]

Here is 256-color palette. Use colorpicker yourself
[image: xterm-256]

Comment: Hmm your background color '#300A24' doesn't show up on the official [Ubuntu Design Color Palette](http://design.ubuntu.com/brand/colour-palette). The closest official colors seem to be the 90% and 100% versions of Dark Aubergine, '#411934' and '#2C001E' respectively.

Answer (score 1):

I just found the Ubuntu colorscheme for iTerm2 here: https://github.com/mbadolato/iTerm2-Color-Schemes/blob/master/schemes/Ubuntu.itermcolors
But I haven't tried it yet.