# Ubuntu purple terminal colors in ConEmu

Tags: windows, colors, conemu

How to set up Unubtu-like terminal colors with purple background?

Inspired by this question: [Ubuntu purple terminal colors to iTerm2](https://superuser.com/q/486238/139371). The answer is some tricky, because terminal background is not one of "Palette color".

Answer (score 18, accepted):

1) First, create small background image with solid color (Red=48, Green=10, Blue=36). Save it as `Purple.png` near to `ConEmu.exe`.

[image: Background image]

2) Set up user palette, groupbox `Standard colors`, see values below (numbers in the end of answer). Choose `#15` in the `Text` dropdown.

[image: Color palette]

3) Enable `Background image`, type `%ConEmuDir%\Purple.png` in the `Path` **and** `#0` in `Replace color indexes` edit field. Choose `Tile` in `Placement` dropdown.

[image: Background settings]

4) Here we are

[image]

Palette color values

```
0:  #2e3436
1:  #3465a4
2:  #4e9a06
3:  #06989a
4:  #cc0000
5:  #75507b
6:  #c4a000
7:  #d3d7cf
8:  #555753
9:  #729fcf
10: #8ae234
11: #34e2e2
12: #ef2929
13: #ad7fa8
14: #fce94f
15: #eeeeec
```

Comment: +1. Wow, did you write this whole thing for that this one question?

Comment: Nope. Only screenshots was taken and color values retrieved. All other features ConEmu supports for a long time.

Comment: I just noticed: "Author of ConEmu - Windows Console Emulator with Tabs." :-)